# Let $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ where $g(x) = 1$ if $ 0\leq x <1 $ and $g(x) = 2$ if $ x=1$ Determine whether g is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $g:[0,1]  \rightarrow  \mathbb{R} $ where $g(x) = 1$  if $ 0\leq x <1 $ and $g(x) = 2$ if $ x=1$ (not sure how to write the long curly bracket in latex)

> **Edited:** Let $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by,
> $$g(x)=\begin{cases}1, \quad \text{if}\quad 0\leq x<1,\\ 2, \quad \text{if}\quad x=1\end{cases}$$

My solution so far:

To show that g is integrable, we have to show that the lower sum and upper sum both converge to the same limit.
I chose the dissection $D_n = (0, 1- \frac{1}{n},1)$. This is a non uniform dissection since the function is discontinuous.

I dont know if i should continue with my solution because im not sure if my choice of dissection is correct. Is it?

Edit: Continuing my solution:
Since i chose $D_n = (0,1-1/n,1)$  \

$m_1 = inf(g[0,1-1/n]) = 1$ 
$m_2 = inf (g[1-1/n,1]) = 1$ 
$\underline {S}(D_n) = (1-1/n) +1/n = 1 \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ \

$M_1 = sup(g[0,1-1/n]) = 1$ 
$M_2 = sup(g [1-1/n,1]) = 2$

$\bar {S}(D_n) = (1-1/n) + 2(1/n) = 1 + 1/n  \rightarrow 1 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ 
The upper sum and lower do converge to the same limit hence g is  integrable.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: There are many partitions of [0,1] you could choose -- this is one of them and should help you make the argument you would like to. As you long you choose some $\varepsilon_n$ that goes to $0$ as $n$ becomes large (like $\varepsilon_n=1/n$, as you did), you're fine.

Comment: @tyo so its fine that i only have 3 points in it?

Comment: More appropriately, the point of your choice of subdivision (or dissection) is that $g$ is not only continuous, but *constant* on $[0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, continue.  Compute the upper and lower sums for $D_n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews fixed it

Comment: @GEdgar I finished my solution. Would you mind checking it?

Comment: @Neels, double-check your last step -- you've written $M_2$ correctly, but $\bar{S}(D_n)$ isn't correct. The length of the last leg of your partition should be $1 - (1 - 1/n)$, not $1$.

Comment: @tyo  silly mistake! thanks! i think i fixed it now. Is it right?

Comment: @Neels yep! and if you wanted to be slick, you could always take $\varepsilon_n = 1/2n$ instead. Regardless, your solution works and you're good to go!